# Windows 10 Build 10586.63 (version 1511) won't sign in to new users

Tags: windows, windows-10, user-accounts

I recently updated my laptop to Windows 10 build 10586.63 (version 1511), and since my mom just lost her computer, I thought I may create her a new user, so she can do her work on my computer.

When I create the account, everything goes without problems. However, when I am about to sign into the user to configure it for the first time, problems appear. The "Welcome" screen is shown, and then it immediately signs out of the user, and takes me back to the sign-in screen.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The issue might be solved by making her account a local one:

How To Create A New Local User Account In Windows 10

- Access the Accounts menu - To do so click on the Start Menu search
  box and enter “add user”.
- Select “Add, edit, or remove other users” from the top of the
  resulting search list.
- Select “Add someone else to this PC”.
- Ignore the prompt to provide an email or phone number. Instead click
  on the link at the bottom that reads “The person I want to add
  doesn’t have an email address”.
- Ignore the information here prompting you to setup a new email address through @outlook.com and click on the link at the bottom “Add a user without a Microsoft account”.

  - Enter your preferred username and password now and click “Next”.

Comment: This is exactly what i've done the entire time, but i can't seem to get it working. I've also tried deleting the account, and then readd it to the computer...
Anything else i can do?